# What's the distinction between T and Any when using Kotlin Generics?

Tags: kotlin, generics

What is the difference?

What is the difference between:

```
class SomeClass<T>(var param: T)
```

and

```
class SomeClass<Any>(var param: Any)
```

?

Is there any difference between them? It looks like these classes work the same way.

Comment: It seems like you shouldn't use the version with `Any` do you have an actual example? You're correct, the generic type name doesn't matter so using `Any` as the name will hide`Any`.

Comment: No, I don't have an example. Just theoretically wondering if there is any difference :)

Comment: Don't use actual class names for your parameter names. It doesn't offer any benefit, but it hides the actual name.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, they are basically the same.

The syntax for declaring a generic class is:

```
class ClassName<GenericClassType>
```

So, in your case, both `T` and `Any` are identifiers. But, the first (`T`) looks like a better choice because `Any` shadows a one of the Kotlin types.

`kotlin.Any` ref: https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-any/).

Comment: "_because Any conflicts with a one of the Kotlin types_."
Could you clarify, please, what type are you talking about?

Comment: @АндрейБаранов The type [`kotlin.Any`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-any/). Cililing is right that in this case `Any` is being treated as an identifier (for a type), not a class name, even though there _is_ a class with that name — which makes the code extremely misleading to anyone reading it! Though perhaps ‘shadows’ would be a more precise term than ‘conflicts with’.